# How to execute Gearman tasks synchronously?

Tags: gearman

I have a question concerning Gearman:

My script based on nested sets. And if one of task fails - we have to stop queue of all other tasks.  All tasks must be performed synchronously.

**That's what I mean:**

```
task 1 - success
task 2 - success
task 3 - success
task 4 - error <--- fails
task 5 - stop (!) don't execute
task 6 - stop (!) don't execute
...
```

I use an extension: https://github.com/filsh/yii2-gearman

**So question is - how to stop the entire queue after a failing one of tasks?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is to empty the queue when a job fail is that correct?

You could execute this command to empty the queue when a job fails:

```
/usr/bin/gearman -t 1000 -n -w -f function_name > /dev/null
```

Another solution, if possible in your logic, would be to create the next job upon success.